# Dlang: How to handle an array of various types

Tags: templates, generics, delegates, d

I'm learning D and I'm playing with ways of handling generic types. In D how can I declare an array that can store delegates with varying input arguments?

In the example I'm trying to partially mimic the way JavaScript uses .addEventListener/.dispatchEvent and to do that i need to store an array of listeners where they will have various event types as input arguments. I'm trying to prevent a lot of type casting back and forth, but I'm stuck at the point where I need to store them in the same array.

```
    import std.stdio;

    class Event {
    }

    class NewEvent : Event {
    }

    class EventTarget {
        void addEventListener(T)(void delegate(T) listener) {
            this.listeners ~ listener;
        }

        void dispatchEvent(T)(T event) {
            foreach (listener; this.listeners) {
                writeln("listener: ", listener, " ", event);
                // TODO: call listener if it's input argument matches the T type
                // if (type is the one matching the listeners first input argument) {
                //  listener(event);
                // }
            }
        }

    private:
        // TODO: find a way to store multiple event types in this array
        void delegate(T)[] listeners;
    }

    void main() {
        auto target = new EventTarget();

        target.addEventListener((NewEvent event) {
            write("executed handler for NewEvent", event);
        });

        target.addEventListener((Event event) {
            write("executed handler for Event", event);
        });

        target.dispatchEvent(new NewEvent());
        target.dispatchEvent(new Event());
    }
```

There is a playground here https://run.dlang.io/is/XdTVBc

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640856/how-to-pass-any-memory-to-a-function-through-another-function

Comment: I would use associative arrays: https://run.dlang.io/is/q3F2Xo

Comment: Or if you want to really use array: https://run.dlang.io/is/A0egqt

Comment: The associative array was also a nice less complicated version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should works:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.traits;

abstract class Event {

}

class NewEvent : Event {
}

class NewEvent2 : Event {
}

class EventTarget {
    void addEventListener(T : Event)(void delegate(T) listener) {
        this.listeners ~= DG(listener);
    }

    void dispatchEvent(T : Event)(T event) {

        foreach (listener; listeners)
        {            
            if (listener.type_name == fullyQualifiedName!T)
            {
                listener(event);
            }
        }
    }

private:    
    DG[] listeners;
}

struct DG
{
    string type_name;
    void delegate(Event) dg;
    alias dg this;
    this(T : Event)(void delegate(T) listener)
    {
        type_name = fullyQualifiedName!T;
        dg = cast(void delegate(Event)) listener;
    }
}

void main() {
    auto target = new EventTarget();

    target.addEventListener((NewEvent event) {
        writeln("executed handler for NewEvent", event);
    });

    target.addEventListener((NewEvent2 event) {
        writeln("executed handler for Event", event);
    });

    target.dispatchEvent(new NewEvent());
    target.dispatchEvent(new NewEvent2());
}
```